# Priority queueing in openvswitch

Tags: sdn

When implementing QOS in openvSwitch there is an option in Conﬁguration for linux-htb QoS : **other_conﬁg : priority**

The description for this option in the ovs documentation is :

> other_conﬁg : priority:optional string, containing an integer, in
>   range 0 to 4,294,967,295 A queue with a smaller priority will receive
>   all the excess bandwidth that it can use before a queue with a larger
>   value receivesany.Speciﬁc priority values are unimportant; only
>   relative ordering matters. Defaults to 0 if unspeciﬁed.

My understanding is this is an option for implementing Priority Queueing. Is this correct ?

And if so, what does the bellow line means exactly ? :

> Speciﬁc priority values are unimportant; only relative ordering
>   matters

Any help woud be appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in a given interval all traffic assigned a lower value will be transmitted before traffic assigned a higher value.  If in that interval the amount of traffic assigned the lower value exhausts the available buffer then the traffic assigned higher values will be dropped.

Edit to Add: Yes, this is absolutely a form of priority queueing.

Comment: Thank you mxrx for your response. Do you have any references that I can look at to deeper my understanding in this matter, please.

Answer (score 0):

> > And if so, what does the bellow line means exactly ? :
> >
> > Speciﬁc priority values are unimportant; only relative ordering matters

Suppose you have to flows with priority 10 and 20 respectively. Now instead of 10 and 20, you can change it to 10 and 11 resp. or 19 and 20 resp. or 50 and 100 resp. You see, the number doesn't matter. Just the relative difference matters.

I am assuming that you must have landed on the man page for ovs. In case you haven't here is the link: [OVS-vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vswitchd.conf.db.5.txt)